# Browser cache effect on coldfusion login

Tags: coldfusion, browser-cache, coldfusion-9

I have a code that has been in the production environment for the past 2 years with no issues, last week our hosting company was down for two days, and when the server got back online, our application started having a particular issue.

This issue is when you try to login, it will bring you back to the login page with no errors.
I submitted a troble ticket and i was asked to clear my browser cache. I cleared my cache and the application started working again.

Is there no other way to resolve this issue without clearing the browser cache?

I have tried several method, I have used

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and also used

```
<cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="yes">
```

Please see the code for Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>

<cfset this.name = "some_app"> 
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,9,0,0)>
<cfset this.clientmanagement= "yes">
<cfset this.ClientStorage = "registry"><!--- this was formally cookie, i changed it to registry, but no change --->
<cfset this.loginstorage = "session" >
<cfset this.sessionmanagement = "yes">
<cfset this.sessiontimeout = createTimeSpan(0,4,0,0)>
<cfset this.setClientCookies = "yes">
<cfset this.setDomainCookies = "yes">
<cfset this.scriptProtect = "all">  
<cfset this.datasource = "some_dsn">

<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" output="false">

    <cfset application.scriptProtect = "all">

    <cfset application.sessions = 0>
    <cfset application.surportmail = "support@some_app.com"> 
    <cfset application.site.url = "http://some_app.com/"/>        
    <cfset application.com.Employee = CreateObject("component","com.user.Employee").init()/>
    <cfset application.com.Appraisal = CreateObject("component","com.Appraisal").init()/> 
    <cfset application.com.Security = CreateObject("component","com.system.Login").init()/>
    <cfset application.com.Log = CreateObject("component","com.adexfe.portal.system.Log").init()/> 
    <cfset application.com.Temp = CreateObject("component","com.adexfe.portal.Temp").init()/>
    <cfset application.com.Util.Security = CreateObject("component","com.adexfe.util.Security").init()/>   
    <cfset application.com.Security.url = application.site.url/>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onApplicationEnd" output="false">
    <cfargument name="applicationScope" required="true">

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onRequestStart">
    <cfargument name="requestname" required=true/>

    <cflock type="exclusive" scope="session" timeout="10">
        <cfparam name="session.IsLogin" default="false" type="boolean" />
        <cfparam name="session.Userinfo" default=""  />
    </cflock>

    <cflock type="readonly" scope="session" timeout="40">
        <cfset request.IsLogin = session.IsLogin>
        <cfset request.UserInfo = session.UserInfo>
    </cflock>
    <!--- Check for login here --->
    <cfif Not request.IsLogin and ListLast(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME,'/') NEQ "login.cfm"  and ListLast(cgi.SCRIPT_NAME,'/') NEQ "forget.cfm">
        <cflocation url="login.cfm" addtoken="no">            
    </cfif> 

    <cfset application.com.Security.url = application.site.url/> 

    <cfset request.Security = application.com.Util.Security/>
    <cfparam name="url.bp" default="#request.Security.URLEncrypt('bp=home')#"/>     
    <cfset url.bpr = url.bp/>
    <cfif listfirst(url.bp,'=') eq 'h'>
        <cfset request.aurl = request.Security.URLDecrypt(listlast(url.bp,'='))/> 
    <cfelse>
        <cfset request.aurl.bp = url.bp/>
    </cfif> 

    <cfset request.aurl.bp = Replace(request.aurl.bp,'.','/','all')>


</cffunction> 

</cfcomponent>
```

Login.cfm code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="Assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Assets/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td width="50%" align="right"><br />      <img src="Assets/img/logo-b.jpg" width="445" height="164" /></td>
    <td><span class="label"> <img src="Assets/img/comp_logo.gif"  vspace="100" hspace="50" /></span></td></tr>
</table>

<cfform name="login">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" >
    <tr><td nowrap class="label"> Email:</td>
    <td><cfinput class="in" name="username" message="Valid email address is required please" type="text" required="yes" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td height="41"  class="label">Password:</td>
    <td><cfinput  class="in" name="Password" style="color:red;"  required="yes" type="password"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td height="41">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" class="sub"/><input name="Captcha" value="" type="hidden"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="forget.cfm">Forget password?</a></td></tr>
</table>
</cfform>

<cfoutput>
<cfif structkeyexists(form,'Captcha')>
    <!---login with user info --->
    <cfset s = createobject("component","com.system.Security").init(false,false)/>
    <cfset l = createobject("component","com.system.Login").init()/>
    <cfset l.url = application.site.url/>
    <cfset l.SignIn(form,s)/>

    <cfif Not l.IsLogin>
        <div align="center" style="color:##F00; font-weight:bold;  text-align:center;">#l.errmsg#</div>
        <cfset application.com.Log.WriteLoginAttempt(form.username)/>
    <cfelse>
        <!--- set session --->
        <cflock type="exclusive" scope="session" timeout="30" throwontimeout="yes">
            <cfset session.IsLogin = true>
            <cfset session.userInfo = application.com.Employee.GetEmployee(l.userInfo.employeeid)/>
        </cflock>
        <cfset application.com.Log.WriteLoginSuccess(form.username,l.userInfo.employeeId)/>
        <cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="no">
    </cfif> 
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Browsers don't cache post requests unless you go out of your way to do so. This sounds like the servers may have changed IP and you have a polluted DNS cache somewhere.

Comment: Does clearing the browser cache also clear the DNS cache?  Another possibility might be that they changed something with CF and the cfform stuff needed it's JS resetting? (Assuming that the instruction to clear the cache wasn't just a blanket response from the hosting company.)

Comment: according to opendns.com, yes. http://www.opendns.com/support/article/67

Comment: Hrm... that article says to select all boxes since beginning of time, which must be overkill, (unless there's some sort of "only clear DNS if everything selected" functionality, which makes no sense). Don't see why there isn't a distinct DNS option. :/

Comment: This isn't a solution, but pressing Ctrl-F5 will force most browsers to reload a page without using the cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear you application variables on the server if you use these commands, also you can use structClear() if you want to reset any of the variables and restart the application. Generally speaking once application variables are set they stay persistent in memory until the application is restarted.

these commands will restart the application.

```
<cfscript> applicationStop(); </cfscript> or <cfset applicationStop()>
```

after the variables have been cleared you can remove that line of code and that should resolve  the caching issue.